# How to run cap deployment on the server

Tags: deployment, capistrano, server-side

Is there any way to have the deployment targeted server run `cap someenv deploy` run itself? Basically I want to setup auto deployment for our development environment based on Github's / Bitbucket's web hooks.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this, but there is some support in Capistrano for running commands on locally rather than through SSH.

When setting up your `deploy/staging`, declare your server using `:local` instead of the hostname. For example:

```
# deploy/staging.rb
server :local, :roles => %w(app db web)
       ^^^^^^
```

Now, if on the server your hook runs `cap production deploy`, the deployment scripts should run locally on the server rather than needing to go through SSH.

Let us know if it works!